# Getting input using pointer to array of structures and printing the output

Tags: arrays, pointers, structure

I am trying to get data into array of structures with pointers using `scanf` function    . Then I am trying to print the output. But the output shows no values after the `printf` is executed. Need help on where did I go wrong?

Here's my code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

struct estore 
{ 
    int pid; 
    char category[20];
    char brand[20]; 
    char model[20]; 
    int price; 
}; //can also be 'stock[5];' The below line is not required in such case 

struct estore stock[5]; 
struct estore *sptr=stock; 

void main() 
{ 
    int j; 
    for(j=0;j<5;j++) 
    { 
        printf("\nEnter Product ID: "); 
        scanf("%d",&(sptr++)->pid); 
        printf("\nEnter Product Category: "); 
        scanf("%s",(sptr++)->category); 
        printf("\nEnter Product Brand: "); 
        scanf("%s",(sptr++)->brand); 
        printf("\nEnter Product Model: "); 
        scanf("%s",(sptr++)->model); 
        printf("\nEnter Product Price: "); 
        scanf("%d",&(sptr++)->price); 
   } 
   for(j=0;j<5;j++) 
   { 
       printf("\nThe Product ID is %d",sptr->pid); 
       printf("\nThe Product Category is %s",(*sptr).category); 
       printf("\nThe Product Brand is %s",sptr->brand); 
       printf("\nThe Product Model is %s",sptr->model); 
       printf("\nThe Product Price is Rs.%d/-",(*sptr).price); 
       sptr++; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Your "question" will probably not be answered for the following reasons. 1) You don't ask any questions. 2) You simply copy pasted some code and didn't format it properly (this is unpleasant to read). 3) You didn't use the tags properly: You should at least add a tag for the programming language of your question. 4) Comment your code, provide useful information for anyone willing to help you. Refer to [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there are many issues, first of all you need to change `sptr++`, in your `scanf` statements, because each `sptr++` wil increment your pointer with 1 index and i am sure you did not intend to that. Second, i don't understand why you are using different syntax for different data types, you need to go through a book first. Even in your printf statements, sometime you are using -> operator, sometimes dot, why on the earth will you do it?? Did this code, which you have posted even compile?

i have fixed it.

```
int main()

{

    int j;

    for (j = 0; j<2; j++)

    {

        printf("\nEnter Product ID: ");

        scanf("%d", &(sptr+j)->pid);

        printf("\nEnter Product Category: ");

        scanf("%s", &(sptr+j)->category);

        printf("\nEnter Product Brand: ");

        scanf("%s", &(sptr+j)->brand);

        printf("\nEnter Product Model: ");

        scanf("%s", &(sptr+j)->model);

        printf("\nEnter Product Price: ");

        scanf("%d", &(sptr+j)->price);

    }
    for (j = 0; j<2; j++)

    {

        printf("\nThe Product ID is %d", (sptr+j)->pid);

        printf("\nThe Product Category is %s",(sptr+j)->category);

        printf("\nThe Product Brand is %s", (sptr+j)->brand);

        printf("\nThe Product Model is %s", (sptr+j)->model);

        printf("\nThe Product Price is Rs.%d/-", (sptr+j)->price);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant..The reason I used dot and -> is I am just testing using different types of instructions

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can accept this answer